# SyntaxError:JSON.parse:unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I've been looking all over for the solution but I cannot find anything that works,I keep getting the following error,I have a submit event that will call the function SUValidation with the data thats being 
submitted through a text box in php form,I have tried putting contentType: "application/json",//note the contentType defintion looking at other posts but nothing helped..can anyone provide guidance on how to debug this error or at the best provide a solution

Error:-

```
SyntaxError:JSON.parse:unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

RESPONSE OF SUVALID.py

```
Just outputs the content of the python script
```

Hi,

submit event:-

```
$("#su_validation").submit(function(event) {
    console.log("su_validation.submit");
    event.preventDefault();
    //SUValidation('#su_validation', '#su_validation_table', '#gerrits_su_validation', showDialog, "#su_validation_dialog");
    $("#SUValidation_su_validation_table").empty();

    var data = { 'product_lines' : [], 'gerrits' : [], 'contacts' : []};
    //find all pl's that are checked
    data['product_lines'] = ($("#product_line_su_validation").val()).split(",");

    data['gerrits'] = ($("#gerrits_su_validation").val()).split(",");
    data['contacts'] = ($("#contacts_su_validation").val()).split(",");
    console.log(data);

    SUValidation(data, '#SUValidation_su_validation_table', '#gerrits_su_validation', "su_validation_form");


});
```

Function call:-

```
function SUValidation(data, table_name, gerrit_form, caller) {
    console.log("su_validation_form");
    console.log(data);

    //console.log($(form_name).find('input, select, textarea').serialize());
    su_validation_return = null;

    //if maintained, we care if they are in ODS
    //if not maintained, we don't really mind if they aren't in ODS database
    var maintained = null;
    console.log("start when");
    $.when(     
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            url: "scripts/suvalid.py",
            timeout: 180000,
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            success : function(response){
                su_validation_return = [];
                console.log("python");
                console.log(response);
                ....
                    }
                }                
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log("error");
                //alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        })      
    ).then(function() {
        console.log("THEN");
        var gerrits = data['gerrits'];
        console.log(su_validation_return);
        var valid_gerrits = true;
        ..................
```

Comment: the JSON object returned from `scripts/suvalid.py` is invalid.

Comment: Open the `Network` tab of Developer Tools, perform your AJAX call, and then look at the `Response` section of the call to see what the script is returning. It's probably printing something before it prints the JSON.

Comment: @PedroLobito --> why is it invalid?how to fix it?

Comment: @Barmar - can you share a link or an example of this can be done?sorry I havent done this before

Comment: Here's a link about debugging with the Developer Tools, but I don't recall if it includes this detail: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners. Just do what I said.

Comment: @Barmar - the link is broken,anyways I am looking for a more  solution oriented answer

Comment: @user3682248 you can validate json here http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Fixed link: http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820

Comment: @user3682248 Until you can tell us what your script is returning, we can't provide a more helpful answer. That's why I suggested you use the debugging tools to see the response.

Comment: @PedroLobito - I already have that link,how do I get the data thats being send to AJAX call?as you can see in my call am passing the data as JSON format

Comment: What you really need to do is post the `suvalid.py` script.

Comment: @user3682248 What you're passing is irrelevant, what matters is what the server is RETURNING. You're getting an error trying to parse the response.

Comment: @Barmar - thanks for the link,F12 is good way to debug,I will use this,please suggest how do I print the data that suvalid.py is returning..

Comment: Go into the Response section, copy it with the mouse, and paste it into your question. Use the `{ }` tool in the SO editor to mark it as code so it will be shown literally.

Comment: @Barmar - Sorry I dont understand your previous response

Comment: @PedroLobito - i have been using console.log,is log.console any different? where exactly should I use log.console to print the response of suvalid.py ?

Comment: @user3682248, sry, my bad, please read `console.log`.

Comment: Go to the Network tab of Dev Tools. Click on `suvalid.py` to see the details of that AJAX call. Then click on `Response` to see the response. Swipe it with the mouse, type Ctl-c to copy it. Then edit your question and paste it with Ctl-v.

Comment: @PedroLobito - I already have console.log(response); please check my call

Comment: @Barmar - nevermind,I got it,I will edit my response

Comment: @PedroLobito - it never goes into the success loop,it prints the console.log("error");

Comment: `suvalid.py` returns HTML, not JSON. You should use `dataType: 'html'`.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't look like `suvalid.py` is designed to be used with AJAX. It's returning an entire HTML document, so it expects to be used as the action of a form.

Comment: @Barmar - I think I understand the problem now,the python script is not doing what its supposed to do,there is a bug and I need to fix it.. special thanks to you for helping how to debug and make me aware of my problem..I can take it up from here

Comment: @Barmar - I made some changes to the script I got rid of the error I shared yesterday,now I get the response as the content of the python script,it just doesnt  run and the content-type:text/x-python is in the response header where as it should be application/json ,can you guide me what could be the problem here,my observation is something is stopping the python script from running..

Comment: Post a new question with the Python script.

Comment: @Barmar - the python script is good for sure because I get the desired output when I run it on my local server,when I put it on the production server it just outputs the content of the python script..what does it mean when a python script being run just outputs the content of the python script?

Comment: It sounds like you haven't configured the server to recognize the `.py` suffix as meaning it's an executable script.